# How to print column name along with value using coalesce

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to print the values of the first not null column in each row of a table. I am using COALESCE for this. But I want to print the name of the column along with the value.

My table looks like this:

```
COL1         |    COL2     |    COL3     |COL4
********************************************************
             |Value of col2|             |Value of col4
---------------------------------------------------------
             |             |Value of col3|Value of col4
---------------------------------------------------------            
Value of col1|             |             |Value of col4
---------------------------------------------------------
             |             |             |
*********************************************************
```

My code is this:

```
declare
  v_count integer;
  v_counter integer;
  cursor c is
    select rowid, coalesce(col1,col2,col3,col4) not_null_value
      from handson_table;
begin
  select count(*) into v_count from handson_table;

  dbms_output.put_line('There are '||v_count||' rows');

  v_counter:=1;

  for r in c
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rpad('*',5,'*')
                         || 'Row Number' || v_counter
                         || rpad('*',5,'*'));

    if (length(r.not_null_value) > 1) then
      dbms_output.put_line(r.not_null_value);
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('All columns of this row is NULL');
    end if;

    v_counter:=v_counter+1;
  end loop;
end;
```

OUTPUT comes like this:

```
There are 4 rows
*****Row Number 1*****
Value of col2
*****Row Number 2*****
Value of col3
*****Row Number 3*****
Value of col1
*****Row Number 4*****
All columns of this row is NULL
```

I want the output like:

```
There are 4 rows
*****Row Number 1*****
col2 : Value of col2
*****Row Number 2*****
col3 : Value of col3
*****Row Number 3*****
col1 : Value of col1
*****Row Number 4*****
All columns of this row is NULL
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
select (case when col1 is not null then 'col1 : ' || col1
             when col2 is not null then 'col2 : ' || col2
             when col3 is not null then 'col3 : ' || col3
             when col4 is not null then 'col4 : ' || col4
             else 'All Null'
        end)
from handson_table;
```

EDIT:

Yes, you can do this with `COALESCE()`, but the simple method doesn't work in Oracle.  So, this does not do what you want:

```
select COALESCE('col1 : ' || col1,
                'col2 : ' || col2,
                'col3 : ' || col3,
                'col4 : ' || col4,
                'All Null')
from handson_table;
```

The problem is that Oracle treats `NULL` as an empty string for the concat.  So, you end up with something like

If you can use a single query, you don't need a PL/SQL code block.

```
select COALESCE(NULLIF('col1 : ' || col1, 'col1: '),
                NULLIF('col2 : ' || col2, 'col2: '),
                NULLIF('col3 : ' || col3, 'col3: '),
                NULLIF('col4 : ' || col4, 'col4: '),
                'All Null')
from handson_table;
```

Comment: Really found your solution great. Doing it with case really takes care of it. But I have a question  is there anyway of doing this with coalesce. I am asking just out of curiosity else your solution is bang on!

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd do it like so:

```
with sample_data as (select 10 id, null col1, 'value of col2' col2, null col3, 'value of col4' col4 from dual union all
                     select 20 id, null col1, null col2, 'value of col3' col3, 'value of col4' col4 from dual union all
                     select 30 id, 'value of col1' col1, null col2, null col3, 'value of col4' col4 from dual union all
                     select 40 id, null col1, null col2, null col3, null col4 from dual)
select id,
       row_number() over (order by id) rn,
       case when col1 is not null then 'col1'
            when col2 is not null then 'col2'
            when col3 is not null then 'col3'
            when col4 is not null then 'col4'
       end name_of_col,
       coalesce(col1, col2, col3, col4) col_value
from   sample_data;

        ID         RN NAME_OF_COL COL_VALUE    
---------- ---------- ----------- -------------
        10          1 col2        value of col2
        20          2 col3        value of col3
        30          3 col1        value of col1
        40          4
```

N.B. I've assumed that your rows have some sort of unique identifier, plus some column to do the ordering of the rows (which, in the sample data I used is the same column I used as the unique identifier)

Comment: Actually there are no unique identifier in my rows and I cant add columns also.